# Network computer's?

Tags: wireless, networking, lan

I'm connected by `wifi connection` with some `network` and this network uses more than `router` to connect with other more PCs by cables (`lan connections`), and I only see all the connected PCs with same router that I'm connected with, I don't see the rest of computers connected to other routers.

So is there a way to see all the connected PCs to the same network ?

Comment: What do you mean by "see"?

Comment: @hakermania    I mean if there is a command or an application cal list all the connected computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `arp` in `terminal` and see the result.

DESCRIPTION

```
   Arp  manipulates or displays the kernel's IPv4 network neighbour cache.
   It can add entries to the table, delete  one  or  display  the  current
   content.

   ARP  stands  for Address Resolution Protocol, which is used to find the
   media access control address of a network neighbour for  a  given  IPv4
   Address.
```